# Присваивание автоинкрементарного значения переменной полю sort в таблице

Tags: mysql

Привет всем. Задача: необходимо назначить новую сортировку с помощью автоинкремента записям таблицы по ид, порядок которых указан в FIND_IN_SET. IN не подходит по понятной причине (нет возможности влиять на порядок - выдернет из базы кто как под руку подвернется). Результат - не работает (# MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк)). Хочу в один запрос все уложить. Я что то неправильно делаю? Есть ли решение моего вопроса?

```
SET @num := 0;
UPDATE table 
SET sort = @num := (@num + 1)
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '1,3,2,5,4,6')
```

Comment: В update можно (и в вашем случае нужно) указывать `order by`, никакой where порядок не гарантирует. А в order by можно использовать функцию `field(id, 1, 3, 2, ...)`

Comment: @Mike огромное спасибо! все супер!